# Objective C dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is being called indefenetly and cause the application to crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5, modalviewcontroller, zbar-sdk

I have a class (called class A) that creates an instance of another class (called class B) . in class A I call a function fro class B that opens the camera to read a QR code . once the QR code is detected the camera feed is dismissed using this line :

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

now in class A I want to use this event handler to do other things (mainly use the nsstring that I just got from the QR code) so I wanted to use the `-(void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` method for that. But I Noticed the following
-if I have the method with an empty body the reader is not dismissed
-if I have the method with anything in it , the application calls indefinitely the function and the application crashes and/or XCode freezes and crashes eventually

is there any alternative to what I am doing? I ideally I would like to do something like that :

```
-(void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    DisplayLabel.text=output;   
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I want to use this event handler" -- what event handler? Post the code for that. Showing a single line isn't very useful, you need to to show it in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example, being that it calls itself, would lead to recursion with no exit condition, unless you meant to pass the message to `super` instead of `self`.